# Drawing Circles on a JFrame using custom painting

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a simple game using Swing with Java have one question about drawing shapes using the built-in objects. Should the objects be created in the constructor and just draw in the paint method or should they be both created and drawn in the paint method?

See below for an example:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{//inheriting JFrame  
    JFrame f;
    
    private Dimension windowSize;
    
    private final int cols, rows; //The number of circles in each col/row
    
    private Ellipse2D[][] circles;
    
    public Window ()
    {  
        cols = 5;
        rows = 5;
        
        //Set window initial size
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();         
        windowSize = new Dimension();
        windowSize.width = (int)(screenSize.width * .4);
        windowSize.height = windowSize.width;
        
        setSize(windowSize);
        
        circles = new Ellipse2D[rows][cols];
        
        initShapes();

        setLayout(null);
        
        setVisible(true);  
    }  
    
    @Override
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
             RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
             RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < circles[0].length; j++)
            {
                g2d.fill(circles[i][j]);
                g2d.draw(circles[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private void initShapes()
    {        
        int r = (int)(windowSize.width * .015); 
        
        //The frame is the region of the screen that will contain the game
        //(excluding a border/margin of 10% all around)
        int frameX = (int)(windowSize.width  * .7);
        int frameY = (int)(windowSize.height * .7);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < circles[0].length; j++)
            {
                int x = (int)(windowSize.width*.15)  + (frameX/(cols-1)) * j;
                int y = (int)(windowSize.height*.15) + (frameY/(rows-1)) * i;
  
                circles[i][j] = new Ellipse2D.Double(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
            }
        }
    }
    

    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        Window window = new Window();  
    }
}
```

Here I am creating the `Ellipse2D` objects in the constructor function and storing them in an array. Then, in the `paint` method, I iterate through the array and paint each one. The other way that I have seen it is more like the following:

```
//...
@Override
        public void paint (Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            
            RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                 RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                 RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            
            g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);  

            int r = (int)(windowSize.width * .015); 

            for(int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < circles[0].length; j++)
                {
                 int x = (int)(windowSize.width*.15)  + (frameX/(cols-1)) * j;
                 int y = (int)(windowSize.height*.15) + (frameY/(rows-1)) * i;
   
                 Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
                 
                 g2d.fill(ellipse );
                 g2d.draw(ellipse );
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        }
//...
```

This feels wrong to have the objects be created in the `paint` method which is recalled repeatedly, but I have seen this. Essentially, my question is just which organization is either more efficient or just best practice.

Comment: 1) Don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting should be done be overriding `paintComponent(...)` of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. 2) A painting method should NOT change the state of the component, only paint the current state. Therefore the object you want to paint should be created externally to the painting method. See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working example and tutorial links on painting.

Comment: Avoid, where possible, creating short lived objects during a painting pass.  Painting is suppose to run as fast as possible and can run often, especially if you're trying to do animation.  This puts an overhead on the GC which can dramatically reduce the performance of your program